# Add a link to the number of R Shiny output, which directs you to another output

Tags: r, shiny, hyperlink

I want to create a R Shiny module which generates an output summarize the min and max and average sales of each department. How to add a hyperlink to the min and max values in the output? By click the link it directs you to another tab showing you the names of salesman whose sale is min or max within that particular department.

How to achieve this using R Shiny?

Thank you so much!

It would be great if you could provide a sample program

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not the best solution, but it does what you asked for. Had to come up with data and an interface.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
        tabsetPanel(
                id = "tabset",
                type = "hidden", #You can comment this line out ti see the tabset panels
                tabPanel(title = "output",
                         dataTableOutput(outputId = "DT")),
                tabPanel(title = "foo",
                         verbatimTextOutput("Salesmanfoo",
                                            placeholder = TRUE),
                         actionButton("Back1",
                                      "Go Back")),
                tabPanel(title = "bar",
                         verbatimTextOutput("Salesmanbar",
                                            placeholder = TRUE),
                         actionButton("Back2",
                                      "Go Back"))
                )
)
        
server <- function(input, output) {
        
        # Simple data frames since you didn't provide any data
        df <- data.frame(department = c("foo", "bar"),
                         minsale = c(40, 20),
                         maxsale = c(90, 60))
        
        sales_foo <- data.frame(name = c("John", "Alex", "Andrea"),
                                sales = c(75, 90, 40))
        
        sales_bar <- data.frame(name = c("Maria","Josh"),
                                sales = c(60, 20))
        
        output$DT <- renderDataTable({datatable(df,
                                     selection = list(mode = "single",
                                                      target = "cell")) %>% 
                                             formatStyle(c("minsale", "maxsale"), 
                                                         cursor = 'pointer')
                                     }) 
        
        observe({
                # access click information
                selection <- input$DT_cell_clicked
                department <- df[selection$row, "department"]
                
                # do nothing if not clicked yet, or the clicked cell is not in the 1st column
                if(is.null(selection$value) || selection$col %in% c(0, 1)) return()
                
                # switch tabsetPanel
                updateTabsetPanel(inputId = "tabset",
                                  selected = department)
                
                # bad solution to output the names
                if(department == "foo"){
                output$Salesmanfoo <- renderText(sales_foo[sales_foo$sales ==  selection$value, "name"])
                }
                if(department == "bar"){
                        output$Salesmanbar <- renderText(sales_bar[sales_bar$sales ==  selection$value, "name"])
                }
        }) %>%
                bindEvent(input$DT_cells_selected)
        
        
        # to jump back to the main tabset panel
        observe({
                updateTabsetPanel(inputId = "tabset",
                                  selected = "output")
        }) %>% 
                bindEvent(c(input$Back1, input$Back2))

}

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```